# QGIS, I uploaded an SVG file as a label. I set the size at 7 however I have two labels appearing massive

Tags: qgis, svg

Here is a photo below. I am using QGIS 2.18.14

[image]

How can I solve this issue and possibly have the labels spread out throughout the rest of the lines and not limited to the ones above?

Answer (score 1):

In my definition query I had Van Wyck Expressway which I did not convert the label feature into its highway number like the other values.

Once I did this the point was shown accordingly.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with some more details about how you set the size of the svg? Did the SVG size depend on the size of the label? (This will make your question more helpful to others with a similar issue.)